# flash the Desktop Pictures in iOS9 when applicationWillEnterForeground from other app in System Task Manager

Tags: ios

When I open my app and jump to other app from System Task Manager in iOS9,and then I return to my app from System Task Manager again, the app will flash the background desktop pictures quickly , after 1s just show my app view.But the question not happen in iOS8

And i test the question and find the the root view controller in UINavigationController is not happen,just happen in the view controller after UINavigationController pushViewController

Click here and show the video.[enter link description here](https://youtu.be/y4SprfQsIqw)

Comment: Are you using beta iOS or Xcode version ? Do you have all the required splash images ? Is there anything at the system console ?

Comment: Is there any message at the device console (you can see it at the Organizer window) ? What about the splash screens, do you have them properly configured ?

Comment: I use iOS9.0 - 9.2.1,and Xcode 7.0 - 7.2. When happen,nothing is printed in the Xcode console, so I can't get any information to solve it. Maybe the problem happen When App enter foreground and actived during view controller render the view

Comment: No thing configured . The View that shown in video  used the default UITableViewController in the storyboard. That View is very very simple controller,and just have two segue to jump to other view controllers.

Comment: You should see the key window background in the worst case, you should not see the home screen once the app is maximized. Did you check only the debug log area or opened The Organizer, selected the device and read its logs ? It doesn't sound likely that there's nothing at all when you open the app.

Comment: I have found the device all log in the Devices(Organizer not contain the log), that just contain some crash without the problem info

Comment: My bad, didn't get used to the changes. If you can reproduce the problem at a small new project I'd recommend to file a bug.

Comment: Thank you A-Live , I find the reason when I  reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the reason that I use the below code in the UINavigationController , I delete it , all is right.

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setBackButtonTitlePositionAdjustment(UIOffsetMake(CGFloat(NSInteger.min), CGFloat(NSInteger.min)), forBarMetrics: UIBarMetrics.Default)
```